# Display previously selected options in select

Tags: javascript, html

Say I've got a  HTML setup with some JS behind.

```
<select id="my-select" onchange="changeFunc()">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
```

But I'm trying to make it so that the select HTML keeps track of which options have been clicked and displays those in the select's display rather than just the most recently clicked item. Some pseudo code might look like.

```
let selectedValues = [];

changeFunc() {
  selectedValues.push(mySelect.value);
  mySelect.DISPLAY = selectedValues.join(', ');
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this effect for a select element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this **two ways either** store the all previously select value in an `array` and display them in div as record **OR** create new `option` in the same select using and append them in an [optgrp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp).

Solution: If you want display the previously `selected` option in the same `select`

**Live Demo**

```js
let recSel = document.querySelector('#record_select')

function changeFunc(e) {
  let opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
  opt.textContent = e.options[e.selectedIndex].textContent
  opt.value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
  recSel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="my-select" onchange="changeFunc(this)">
  <optgroup label="Current Select">
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Previous Selected" id="record_select">
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Solution: If you want display the previously `selected` records in a div with `join(',')`

**Live Demo:**

```js
let selectedValues = [];
let recSel = document.querySelector('#record_select') //get el

//Store value
function changeFunc(e) {
  selectedValues.push(e); //store selected value
  recSel.textContent = selectedValues.join(', '); //display record of selected values
}
```

```html
<select id="my-select" onchange="changeFunc(this.value)">
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
</select>

<div id="record_select"></div>
```